# Saving the content of an html input box

Tags: python, html, txt

How can I save the contents of an input box into a .txt file in html?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>I am gonna steal your name</title>
    </head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="../Practise/html input.txt">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/html input.txt".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `action` has to point to the Python application that processes the input. You could use Flask for this.

Comment: Into *what* text file? Do you want it to be created on the user's computer, or on the server?